# Adding Password With Special Characters to WildFly Credential Store

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-26

I am configuring a [second] datasource in WildFly and I seem to be having trouble adding the password to the credential store. I can create the datasource (and connect) using the clear-text password option; but when I add the password to and attempt to use the credential store I get a password authentication error. The password has the following characters: '!?'. I know the '!' and '?' should be escaped when not using the credential store. I have tried using "" and {} both with and without escaping the characters and nothing appears to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other special characters, I did also need to escape the '\' characters in the password. My issue apparently was the updates I was making to the credential store were not being used until the  credential store was reloaded. I discovered this by writing a quick REST end-point to grab the credential store and return the stored (plain text) password for a specific alias.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).